# local JSON Enum decoding

Tags: ios, json, swift, file-manager

How can I decode JSON to Enum in my model?
where am i doing wrong?
If you wish, I can share my Json decode codes, but my json decode codes are working fine.

**Error:**

```
typeMismatch(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "questions", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "sections", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode String but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))
Question_App/JSONProvider.swift:55: Fatal error: Error decoding JSON
```

**Local JSON**

```json
{
    questions: [
        ....
        {
            "number": 1,
            "question": "What is the chemical formula for water ?",
            "sections": {
                "A": "CO2",
                "B": "H2O",
                "C": "C2H6O",
                "D": "H2N"
            },
            "price": 5,
            "correct": 1
        },
        ....
    ]
}
```

**Model**

```swift
struct QuestionContainer: Codable, Hashable {
    var questions: [Question]?
}

enum Section: String, Codable, Hashable {
    case A, B, C, D
}

struct Question: Codable, Hashable {
    var number: Int?
    var question: String?
    var sections: Section?
    var price: Int?
    var correct: Int?
}
```

Comment: Making `Section` a struct instead of a `enum` might be another solution.

Answer (score 1):

`sections` property on `Question` needs to be a dictionary

```swift
struct Question: Codable, Hashable {
    var number: Int?
    var question: String?
    var sections: [Section: String]?
    var price: Int?
    var correct: Int?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have static 4 keys

```
struct Section: Codable, Hashable {
    var a, b, c, d:String
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
       case a = "A"
       case b = "B"
       case c = "C"
       case d = "D"
    }
}
```

otherwise use a dictionary